# What makes a circuit bootable or capable of runnning an OS?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cpu, bootloader, operating-system, gpu

*I posted this on StackOverflow for the premise that any programmer (not an HTML coder, who does not, strictly speaking, do programming, though HTML does require a lot of specific knowledge and bears a certain resemblance to programming) should be familiar with this information and be able to answer. However, I got a downvote and a suggestion to post here instead. So I am doing.*

I'd like to clarify for myself the following area.

Let's consider the universum of Integrated Circuits. An FPGA, a DSP, a USB controller chip, a CPU and a GPU are all examples of IC. However, I realize that a USB controller, or an FPGA can not "run an operating system", whereas a CPU can. Another source of confusion arose when in a lecture, we were told that "Xeon PHI (the older one, pre-Knights Landing) runs an independent operating system and can be booted, thus you need to communicate with it over the network". As far as I understand, this differentiates the Phi from say a GPU which while physically being on the same PCI-E bus is a "slave" device to the CPU.

To make this question exact, let me outline the following points:

Does "this IC is bootable" equal "this IC can run an operating system"?
What makes an IC capable of the above (e.g. if we compare an ASMedia USB controller and a CPU, both of which are physically pieces of binary-code-executing silicon)?

What does it mean exactly that an IC is running an OS, how are the processes on the silicon different for say a USB controller and a CPU?

This may be dubbed broad but I've put it as precise as possible. Basically it's a single question, but broken down into pieces for clarity.

Comment: Yeah, this is kinda broad, and probably difficult to answer in any helpful way without knowing what _you_ know already. For me as an embedded developer, an "OS" can be as small as a few lines of code. For you, maybe an OS is something you can play with using a mouse.

Comment: The problem isn't that you asked on the wrong site, the problem is that you asked a bad question.  "Bootable" has no clear singular agreed upon meaning.  You can talk about something that is a *stored program computer* but then you get into distinctions between those where you can vs. cannot change the program, and the various meanings of "you cannot" ie, mask ROM, OTP, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton well that's exactly what I'd like to understand, what is bootable and what is an OS, for I've been pretty sure (up until seeing your comment) that those things are well defined.

Comment: @pipe for me, an OS is something that gives me control over a hardware, as opposed to a fixed-function silicon like USB controller or such. On the other hand, a GPU is programmable, yet there is no way to "boot" into it. This is something I'm looking to understand.

Comment: An FPGA that has been programmed appropriately can absolutely run an operating system.

Comment: @duskwuff that's a revelation to me, could you post a link to an example?

Comment: This is far too broad and not an appropriate question here.  Fundamentally, the first thing you have to decide in asking something with non-agreed-upon terms is *why you care* because an answer only has meaning in the context of that.

Comment: This is really disappointing, because I've asked about a dozen questions already that have been dubbed as inapproapriate whereas to me they are important and I realize I lack the knowledge.

Comment: @iksemyonov http://xilinx.wikidot.com/microblaze-linux among others

Comment: @iksemyonov it sounds like you haven't understood then that Stack Exchange sites are intended only for specific, clear questions.  They are not intended as an all purpose source of knowledge.  Reference materials really should come first.

Comment: Basically, I have the feeling that today, on stackoverflow e.g. anything further than "how do I do X in framework Y" is off-topic and downvoted, while years ago questions like mine would gain traction.

Comment: @iksemyonov Maybe it's important to remember that not every question is suitable for the StackExchange websites. The Question & Answer format is tailored to _focused_ questions with a clear and distinct answer. You want to learn the general concepts about computing hardware. That's _great_, but it may still be a bad fit for StackExchange.

Comment: @ChrisStratton then how did e.g. "what is the stack and the heap" become a hundred or thousand-upvoted on SO years ago? Can call that broad as well for there are many execution models and hardware designs.

Comment: @pipe yeah the line seems to be really thin at times between a fitting question and a non-fitting one. I'll try getting in touch with my CS profs then; though being on the graduation doorstep may deem me officially ineligible for prof advice, sort of.

Comment: @iksemyonov The answers to [This question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71765/ok-to-ask-a-professor-at-my-institution-with-whom-i-have-no-previous-relationshi) indicates that the professors would not care, as long as you're showing interest in their subject.

Comment: @pipe great link thank you! The only real fear i have however is that this what I;'m asking here may be basics and I may be expected to know it form the very first years in college; however my bachelor's was a rather bad program, and I'm not sure if that would be an excuse for me not to know this stuff being a graduate.

Comment: What's the difference between "doing USB controller stuff" and "running a USB controller operating system"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're searching for a distinction which is more philosophical than practical. It's very Wittgenstein's Ladder.

> where is the line that separates one programmable IC from another one, that allows the first one to run an OS

How do you distinguish an OS from other types of program? You could say that a program that loads other programs under user control is an *operating system*, and that the first program a processor runs from ROM or EPROM which loads other programs is the *bootloader*.

Then you start having problems with boundary cases. Some microcontrollers can only be reprogrammed externally. Conversely, GPUs are fully general processors with a weird architecture; an NVIDIA GPU has its own BIOS which boots a task-scheduling operating system. The Raspberry Pi is another example: the GPU starts first, running a boot ROM which reads the SD card and [starts the boot sequence for the ARM processor](https://thekandyancode.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/how-the-raspberry-pi-boots-up/) (three stages of programs-loading-programs before the ARM even is allowed to execute an instruction!).

FPGAs make the distinction even more complex. The FPGA loads a 'bitstream' at start to define its function. That might include a processor or several, which then need to load code from somewhere.

Then there's systems like the isolated secure processor on the iPhone. It does get 'booted', but it will only run code signed with Apple's keys.

More useful questions are things like "does this device have firmware which can be replaced after manufacture", or "does this have an MMU which would allow me to run a memory-protected operating system like Linux".

Answer (score 2):

Ok, back to basics. A processor executes instructions stored in some type of memory. It is designed so that the user can change the instructions when required. So one processor can do many different things depending on the programming.

The processor achieves this by having hardware that is general purpose. It fetches the instruction, decides what needs to be done, and executes the instruction. For example, the RISC pipeline is one solution:
[image: risc]

An ASIC, like an Ethernet PHY, is designed to do one thing. It does not change. This means it needs less hardware resources than a processor, and can be much faster. All the instruction fetching and decoding is not necessary anymore.

Now, an operating system consists of a kernel that removes the need to interface to the hardware aka abstraction. It boots in the sense that there is a boot loader in the form of processor instructions. The boot loader loads the kernel in memory, which again is a set of processor instructions. The boot loader then passes control to the kernel, and the kernel can boot the OS, and start executing user code. The kernel acts as a buffer between the hardware and the user side software.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Now where would a GPU sit in this scheme of things? It is programmable via shaders and older immediate mode, yet there is no way to run an OS on a GPU. What am I missing?

Comment: So, a GPU is not a general purpose processing unit. In effect it is a matrix multiplication engine. Its primary purpose in life is to do one specific function: arithmetical operations. That is why you need a CPU in your computer.

Comment: But it is programmable, isn't it? Then where is the line that separates one programmable IC from another one, that allows the first one to run an OS, and forbids the other one? Is the line "capable of performing general purpose instructions"? Or is it that the CPU also handles the buses and data flow?

Comment: There is no singular fixed dividing line between CPU's, GPU's and DPS's - various chips have various features.  All you are doing is proving that your question lacks the definition to be a fit here.

Comment: The line is that an OS is designed to run on a general purpose processing unit.

Comment: There are many kinds of operating systems, many of which you would not recognize.  What is a "general purpose processing unit" ?   Most chips are better at some things than others, and many can do things they weren't primarily intended to.  There are also many processors of *general* purpose which are most often used without anything that could be fairly labeled an operating system.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I would define it as being able to do three things: move data, branch, and compute arithmetical and logical operations.

Comment: Pretty much everything mentioned on this page can do that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton of course, thank you for the effort, I appreciate it; it's probably my way of seeing things broadly and top-down that doesn't fit on stackexchange.

Comment: @ChrisStratton well, yeah. And you can put an OS, if you really wanted to, but that will not be the intended use of the device. It all comes down to cost vs benefit. It's like this heater app for the iPhone, where it overloaded the processor with instructions in order to generate heat. Just because something can be done, doesn't mean it is a good idea.

Comment: "there is no way to run an OS on a GPU" - quite a lot of the modern ones are already running an OS provided by the manufacturer, who have either deliberately prevented or not provided any mechanism for you to replace it with a different one.